Qiskit runtime error on hardware but not on simulator
I am trying to run a circuit on hardware. But I get the following error, which is not really helpful tbh.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int

It is unclear how to debug this as it only happens on hardware. The circuit runs successfully on the Aer simulator.
The following code I used to send it to the hardware.
# Initialize account.
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel='ibm_quantum', token='TOKEN')

backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
#backend = FakeManilaV2()

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(target=backend.target, optimization_level=1)

isa_circuit = pm.run(qc)
pubs = []
for observable_operator in observable_operators:
    isa_obs = observable_operator.apply_layout(isa_circuit.layout)
    pubs.append((isa_circuit,isa_obs))

To run it on sim I uncomment the
#backend = FakeManilaV2() and comment the line above it
And send it to the backend as follows:
with Session(backend=backend) as session:
    # Submit a request to the Estimator primitive within the session.
    estimator = EstimatorV2(mode=session)
    estimator.options.resilience_level = 1  # Set options.
    job = estimator.run(pubs)
    for idx, pub_result in enumerate(job.result()):
      print(f"Expectation values for pub {idx}: {pub_result.data.evs}")


Can you also put your code when using a simulator please?

And when sending your job on the backend vs running it on a simulator

added the information

In the circuit I made use of ancillary qubits. After replacing these with ordinary qubits the circuit ran successfully.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Bad bot. Answer is clear.
